# Determining if a language is in P or NP?

Tags: computational-complexity

Is the following language in P or NP?

**EMPTY_TM = {⟨N⟩| N is a TM that accepts no input}**

Can someone shed some light on how to come to such a conclusion also?

Comment: Removed incorrect group-theory tag.  A language must be decidable to be in P or NP in the first place.  Also, P and NP are not mutually exclusive (nor exhaustive) options.

Comment: Doesn't that language bear similarities to another language you've learned about?

Comment: My guess is that it is not in P since you need to simulate each TM N on every string to verify that the language produced by N is empty??

Comment: EMPTY_TM is undecidable, therefore not in P

Comment: You might want to look at [Rice's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)